# Не удаётся установить диспетчер PHP на Windows Server 2019

Tags: php, windows, веб-сервер

Здраствуйте, мне не удаётся установить диспетчер PHP на Windows Server 2019. Мне выпадает вот такая ошибка, которая отражена на скриншоте.
[image: Ошибка от Web Platform Installer при установке диспетчера PHP]

Comment: загрузите пакет вручную и установите. зачем вам вообще такой древний пхп?

Comment: Вручную не получается, так как выдаёт ошибку 404

Comment: что 404? на сайте МС вбейте в поиск название пакета и скачайте под нужную версию